# Checking for existance of value in MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, express

I am developing a user authentication system with expressjs. Therefore to store user data i use a mysql database... When I query to my database I do it with this: `SELECT password FROM USERS WHERE email=EmailHere`
The problem with this is I dont know an elegant solution to returning an error message if the email doesnt exist. Somewhat understandable?

**So to conclude**: I want to know if that value exists when I query to the db so I dont get an error message.

**Edit:**

```
  const query = `SELECT password FROM USERS WHERE email=?;`;
  let [rows, fields] = await db.promise().query(query, [req.body.email]);

  const password = rows[0].password;
  console.log(password);
```

This gives me the error: Cannot read properties of undefined reading 'password'.

So it is trying to access the .password column. Can I prevent that?

*Thanks in advance! Have a great day*

Comment: You shouldn't be getting an error message. If the entry doesn't exist you'll get 0 rows returned and this is your indicator that it doesn't exist. Are you quoting your email address?

Comment: Yes just updated the code for the error message... Forgot to include that :D

Comment: Look at the length of the `rows` array before assuming that `row[0]` exists. This is my assumption, I've never actually done SQL in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ok it turns out:**

If I check if the length of the rows Array > 0 it fixes the problem. In the else statement I can just log out an error message to say the user does not exist. This could look something like this:

```
if (!rows.length > 0) return res.status(400).send('User doensnt exist!');
const password = rows[0].password;
// Declaring the variable after I know it exists.
```

Thanks to @danblack for this answer!